# bootstrap tab-pane not growing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a panel with three tabs.

each tab is like this:

```
  <div class="tab-pane alert alert-info" id="step-by-step">
    <form data-toggle="validator" role="form" id="Add_Bike">
      <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6">
        <label for="Year">Year</label>
```

I have a strange problem, if I add the "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6" classes the panel background won't match the form height,

http://jsfiddle.net/YXuNr/8/

[image: not growing]

while it's perfectly fine if I remove the responsive classes

http://jsfiddle.net/9p3s9/1/

[image: growing correctly]

I've checked the html and apparently it's all good, I wouldn't like to force a min-height on these panels, do you have any idea how to fix this? (I've also tried to assign a background and removing the alert alert-info from the tab-pane, but it won't grow anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for some reason adding

```
    <div class="row"></div>
```

after the form fixes this

http://jsfiddle.net/YXuNr/20/

Comment: If someone could provide an explanation why this occurs, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want, I created a css class and added that to the html while removing "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6". It is a bit of a trick but it gets the desired affect you are after. You might want to adjust the position to match it exactly.

**HTML snippet:**

```
<div class="form-group option">
```

**css code:**

```
.option{
  padding-left: 15px;

}
```

**Fiddle:** 
http://jsfiddle.net/YXuNr/9/

Comment: not sure of what you did, but it's not the desired effect, the problem I have right now is that the blue background of the panel is not matching the form height.

Comment: apologies, it seems my fiddle didnt save. I will edit my answer one second.

Comment: Hey, yes that would work, unless i really wanted to keep those  "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6" classes see http://jsfiddle.net/YXuNr/11/

Comment: I tried to narrow it down by removing the classes, but it seems even using one class eg "col-xs-12" throws it out of position.

Comment: It could be a possible bug, but I would make sure to check html and css first and browsers? have you tried this in other browsers?

Comment: yes, it happens the same on other browsers, I'll try to open an issue and see where it goes. thanks for stepping in though

Comment: I think that might help, but like you mentioned if you didnt want to keep those classes you can do something hacky to make it work. cheers

Comment: here's the issue opened on github for reference: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13962